# django-registration-redux Manual Account Activation

Tags: django, django-registration

I'm using `django-registration-redux`.

Everything is set up and working but my question is: can I allow user registration and not send them an activation link? I want to restrict access to the site, and activate accounts manually from the admin view. I can't find information about this case anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

If you are prepared to switch to django-registration this backend https://django-registration.readthedocs.org/en/2.0.3/simple-workflow.html is close to what you want.  You could copy it and just remove the lines that authenticates and logs in the user.

https://github.com/ubernostrum/django-registration/blob/master/registration/backends/simple/views.py